# An easy android 2D game engine with an easy learning curve

Tags: android

Hey all.... I am currently trying to make a game on the android platform. I want some guidelines on choosing a good android 2D game engine. I have been looking on the internet for sometime and have found these game engines to choose from the one which doesn't have a huge learning curve

AndEngine

libGdx (The one m most impressed by)

JMonkeyEngine

For anyone who wants to know more about the different game engines the following link should help you..

http://www.cuteandroid.com/ten-open-source-android-2d-or-3d-game-engine-for-android-developers

I intend to keep the interface simple yet attractive, so want to choose the correct engine, and also want to choose the correct engine using which making complex games also is easy in my future projects. If some one could tell me commercially used free (or open sourced) game engines i would be really grateful. I even wouldn't mind learning a 3D game engine if its learning curve is not that too steep and its implementation of 2D games is also pretty simple.

Answer (score 1):

Andengine hides most of the complexity from you, so its super easy to get started, but because of this you do not have full control over it. The documentation or javadocs is close to zero, so dont expect anything from there.

As for libgdx, its harder to learn, but the community is bigger and more matured, and u have more control to the engine.

no idea about the monkey engine.

Comment: How much time will i be needing to learn libgdx approximately (in weeks)? Can u point me to any games that were made with these engines and any popular game engines used in making games on android? I tried to Google this but didn get much...